# Find directory on different server

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I have a website on Server A and it needs to find a directory on Server B.

On my aspx page, I have:

```html
<mb:FileSystemDataSource
    ID="fileSystemDataSource" runat="server"
    RootPath="\\servername\Folder\Subfolder"
    FoldersOnly="true" />
```

mb is assembly name alias.

On my aspx.cs page, I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable gridviewSource = DisplayFilesInGridView();
    DataRow gridviewRow;

    //sets the server path so it does not default to current server
    string ServerPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        "//",
        this.fileSystemDataSource.RootPath);

    //Get All Folders Or Directories and add in table
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(ServerPath));
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
}
```

Well, it throws an error on the Server.MapPath because it cannot find the server.
I am connected to the network. 
I looked at IIS, and I am pretty sure that is not the problem. If so, I would really need specifics. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that share on serverB open to everyone? If not, have the appdomain for the website run under an domain account and grant that account permission on the share

Comment: it is already open to this domain because other code on the same site accesses that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string ServerPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    "//",
    this.fileSystemDataSource.RootPath);
```

Are you sure that `"//"` is what you're looking for?  UNC paths start with `"\\"`. Try running your program in debug mode and see what the actual `ServerPath` string turns out to be.

Comment: when I do that, there is no compiler error so maybe it is finding the server. It still does not list my directories, but that could be a different problem. also, running in debug mode makes it debug the whole site...I just do view in browser for a specific page.

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/oldrabbit/Public/Intranet2007Docs'.

Answer (score 0):

So Directory does not like Server.MapPath. I have to hard code the UNC string into the Directory constructor.